# The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. This is repeated error

Tags: android, performance

> I have written the following code and there comes an error while launching the application.
>
> **The error is Application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PowerManager pm= (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "my Tag");
        wl.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you given the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the required permission set in your Manifest? Use this in your mainfest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have used this in manifest file. Yet there is problem.